# Using mutate with a stored list of columns and procedures

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to iterate through a stored list of columns and procedures to create n new columns based on this list. In the example below, we start with 3 columns, `a, b, c` and two simple functions `func1, func1`.

The data frame `col_mod` contains two sets of modifications that should be applied to the data frame. Each of these modifications should be an addition to the data frame, rather than replacements of the specified columns.

In `col_mod` row 1, we see that column `a` should be modified using `func1`, and in row 2, we see that column `c` should be modified using `func2`. The new names of these columns should be `a_new` and `c_new`, respectively.

At the bottom of the reprex below, I obtain my desired result, but I would like to do so without hard coding each modification individually . Is there any way to use maybe something from `purrr:map` or anything similiar?

```
library(tidyverse)

## fake data
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
                  b = 6:10,
                  c = 11:15)

## functions
func1 <- function(x) {x + 2}
func2 <- function(x) {x - 4}

## modification list
col_mod <- data.frame("col" = c("a", "c"),                      
                  "func" = c("func1", "func2"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## desired end result
dat %>% 
  mutate("a_new" = func1(a),
         "c_new" = func2(c))
```

**edit:** if it is easier to store the modifications in a list, as shown below, a solution using that would be fine as well, as I am able to store the modifications in either a data frame or list.

```
col_mod <- list("set1" = list("a", "func1"),
                "set2" = list("c", "func2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with the help of `Map`, use `match.fun` to apply the function

```
dat[paste0(col_mod$col, '_new')] <- Map(function(x, y) match.fun(y)(x), 
                                      dat[col_mod$col], col_mod$func)
dat

#  a  b  c a_new c_new
#1 1  6 11     3     7
#2 2  7 12     4     8
#3 3  8 13     5     9
#4 4  9 14     6    10
#5 5 10 15     7    11
```

Using `col_mod` as dataframe.

```
col_mod <- data.frame("col" = c("a", "c"),"func" = c("func1", "func2"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak - I tried your solution but I am getting the following error: "Error in match.fun(y) : 'dots[[2L]][[1L]]' is not a function, character or symbol"

Comment: Are you using this on the data shared or some other data?

Comment: yup. copied and pasted my original sample data and your solution and hit run. same error message. restarted r as well but no luck

Comment: Ok..I see. You are on  R < 4.0.0. Try with `col_mod <- data.frame("col" = c("a", "c"),
                      "func" = c("func1", "func2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `tidyverse` approach to do this

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
imap_dfc(deframe(col_mod), ~ dat %>% 
     transmute(!! str_c(.y, "_new") := match.fun(.x)(!! rlang::sym(.y)))) %>% 
   bind_cols(dat, .)
```